# Ubuntu on Mac (dual-boot). Where do I install GRUB?

Tags: unix, grub

When installing Ubuntu, I choose to install GRUB on a partition *other than*:

```
/dev/sda i.e. /dev/disk0
```

as this is stated in various [tutorials](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation).

However, this way I end up with the error message: **Missing Operating System**

When installing GRUB in `/dev/sda` everythings works fine. Why?

---

@ mods: I hope this is not off-topic, as this a problem with the EFI boot on a Mac, I assume. If I'm wrong, please migrate this question to askubuntu.

Comment: When your trying install Grub are you running from a Ubuntu Live CD?

Comment: @MrDaniel Yes. I install Ubuntu using a Live CD.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new partion from within OS X, then install http://refit.sourceforge.net/ and then ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation